# How to copy chart from excel to word and embed chart data in word file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have excel with data that I'm writing in word, it is open and I try to copy chart from excel to word, without linking it, so that any other user can open it without static link to original excel file.

```
Sub Make4Segment(Wapp As Object)
Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim MyChart As ChartObject
   Set Sheet = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DOC")
   Set MyChart = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DOC").ChartObjects("C1")
   MyChart.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
   With Wapp.Application.Selection.Range
       .PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChart
    End With
End sub
```

I'm getting error 4605 on paste line.

Comment: Try `.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject` instead of `.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChart`

Comment: It changes appearance and size of chart. Also I need series data when I edit it, but no link to original file.

Comment: Use `DataType:=26` for that

Comment: If I use .PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteShape it does not resize chart, however if I press edit data on chart in word, it is accessing original excel file, that word user will not have.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want like this. Can you share screenshots of what you are looking for ? Also, I asked you to use `DataType:=26`

Comment: it is like this https://failiem.lv/u/dapzyu5w

Comment: You can paste it as Image if you don't want data to be connected. There is no option where you can transfer data as well to Word.

Comment: There is, as I have document like this https://failiem.lv/u/6ehyuqaf . I'm trying to replicate it. See difference?

Comment: Which option do  you choose manually when you paste this chart ?

Comment: Have no idea, I got it from coworker as example. It is in word file, word file can be sent around without linking data to excel file. And data for that chart is in word file, when you click on edit chart.

Comment: Actually, that appears when you manually insert a chart n Word. It have it's own Excel Spreadsheet with data. Try it yourself once, add a chart in Word.

Comment: You can try and copy the Data from Excel and insert new chart in Word for this.

Comment: Hmm yes I want to recreate it but with macro. Better would be to copy chart, because I want to keep formatting, and then somehow break link with excel, and store data in word for that chart.

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

`.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChart`

**With:**

`.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=26`

That should paste the Object correctly with Data and Without Link

You can Try with [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdpastedatatype) different datatypes if this one is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To reader in future: I was unable to find easy copy/paste solution to copy chart form excel to word. So I created this monstrosity. It creates chart in word, copies data for chart form excel file and embeds data in word file. Loads chart settings from excel files cells for ease of changing chart appearance. Resulting word document is independent and with chart data, and can be sent to anyone.

```
Sub GenerateReport()
Dim Wapp As Object
    'Launches word application
    Set Wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Wapp.Visible = True
    Wapp.Activate
...
   Call CreateChart(Wapp)
End Sub

'Procedure, that creates chart in Word
Sub CreateChart(Wapp As Object)    
Dim Ch4y As Word.InlineShape
Dim EmChData As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SrDataSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim FomtCh As Excel.ChartObject
Dim DbWidth As Double
Dim DbHeight As Double
Dim DbIndentCh As Double
Dim DbLineWeight As Double
Dim DbDegrees As Double
Dim DbChLeHeight As Double
Dim DbChLeWidth As Double
Dim DbChLeLeft As Double
Dim DbChLeTop As Double
Dim LnChType As Long
Dim LnXLabelSpace As Long
Dim LnYMayorUnit As Long
Dim LnYMinimumScale As Long
Dim LnChBorder As Long
Dim LnChFontSize As Long
Dim BoLegend As Boolean
Dim BoTitle As Boolean
Dim In1 As Integer
Dim In2 As Integer
Dim In3 As Integer
Dim In4 As Integer
Dim In5 As Integer
Dim In6 As Integer
Dim In7 As Integer
Dim In8 As Integer
Dim In9 As Integer
Dim StChFont As String
    'Creates new chart in word
    Set Ch4y = Wapp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddChart2
    'Embed data in chart, to make it independent form excel
    'Creates reference to place where data will be stored
    Set EmChData = Ch4y.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    'Creates reference to source data sheet
    Set SrDataSh = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DOC")
    'Loads data from Excel sheet for customizability
    DbWidth = SrDataSh.Range("A159").Value '490
    DbHeight = SrDataSh.Range("A160").Value '180
    DbIndentCh = SrDataSh.Range("A161").Value '0
    LnChType = SrDataSh.Range("A162").Value '4
    BoLegend = SrDataSh.Range("A163").Value 'True
    BoTitle = SrDataSh.Range("A164").Value 'False
    In1 = SrDataSh.Range("A166").Value '139
    In2 = SrDataSh.Range("A167").Value '231
    In3 = SrDataSh.Range("A168").Value '246
    In4 = SrDataSh.Range("A170").Value '0
    In5 = SrDataSh.Range("A171").Value '133
    In6 = SrDataSh.Range("A172").Value '155
    DbLineWeight = SrDataSh.Range("A173").Value '1.75
    DbDegrees = SrDataSh.Range("A174").Value '90
    LnXLabelSpace = SrDataSh.Range("A175").Value '1
    LnYMayorUnit = SrDataSh.Range("A176").Value '10
    LnYMinimumScale = SrDataSh.Range("A177").Value '70
    LnChBorder = SrDataSh.Range("A178").Value '-4142
    StChFont = SrDataSh.Range("A179").Value 'Open Sans
    LnChFontSize = SrDataSh.Range("A180").Value '9
    In7 = SrDataSh.Range("A182").Value '151
    In8 = SrDataSh.Range("A183").Value '151
    In9 = SrDataSh.Range("A184").Value '151
    DbChLeHeight = SrDataSh.Range("A185").Value '18
    DbChLeWidth = SrDataSh.Range("A186").Value '200
    DbChLeLeft = SrDataSh.Range("A187").Value '140
    DbChLeTop = SrDataSh.Range("A188").Value '155
    'Clears range
    EmChData.Range("A1:XFD1048576").Clear
    'Copy data
    EmChData.Range("A1:C49").Value = SrDataSh.Range("B109:D157").Value
    'Set Source data
    Ch4y.Chart.SetSourceData Source:="'Sheet1'!$A$1:$C$49", PlotBy:=xlColumns
    'Create reference to excel chart
    Set FomtCh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Doc").ChartObjects(1)
    With Wapp
        With .Selection
            'This line change position of chart that will be created to left or to right
            .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = DbIndentCh
        End With
    End With
    'Creates needed formating
    With Ch4y
        'Set size for chart
        .Width = DbWidth
        .Height = DbHeight
        With .Chart
            'Sets chart type
            .ChartType = LnChType
            'Sets chart legend to visible/unvisable
            .HasLegend = BoLegend
            'Sets chart title visible/unvisable
            .HasTitle = BoTitle
            'Sets color back to original for data series lines (for some reason it is not pasted in previous line)
            .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(In1, In2, In3)
            .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(In4, In5, In6)
            'Sets line thicknes
            .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = DbLineWeight
            .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Weight = DbLineWeight
            'Works with x-axis
            With .Axes(xlCategory)
                'Sets orientation of x axis labels
                .TickLabels.Orientation = DbDegrees
                'Force to show all month under x-axis
                .TickLabelSpacing = LnXLabelSpace
            End With
            'Works with y-axis
            With .Axes(xlValue)
                'Sets unit size for y-axis
                .MajorUnit = LnYMayorUnit
                'Sets value on y-axis from where values will start (Changes y=0 to value specified)
                .MinimumScale = LnYMinimumScale
            End With
            With .ChartArea
                'Sets border to none
                .Border.LineStyle = LnChBorder
                'Sets font
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = StChFont
                'Sets font size
                .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = LnChFontSize
                'Sets chart font color
                .Font.Color = RGB(In7, In8, In9)
            End With
            'Checks if Legend for chart is enabled
            If .HasLegend = True Then
                With .Legend
                    'Sets height of legend
                    .Height = DbChLeHeight
                    'Sets width of legend
                    .Width = DbChLeWidth
                    'Sets distance from left side of chart
                    .Left = DbChLeLeft
                    'Sets distance from top side of chart
                    .Top = DbChLeTop
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```